# Getting "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType" Error While Scraping Data with Scrapy

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

I am working on a web scraping project using Scrapy, and I'm encountering a "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes, or bytearray, not NoneType" error. Interestingly, despite this error, I'm still able to scrape most of the data I need.

Here's the relevant part of my Scrapy spider code:

```
def start_requests(self):
        # Generate requests with different payloads for check-in and check-out dates
        for payload in self.checkin_checkout():
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=self.api_url,
                headers=self.headers,
                body=payload,
                method='POST',
                callback=self.parse,
                dont_filter=True,
                meta={'dpayload': payload}  # Pass the payload as metadata
            )
def checkin_checkout(self):
      # Generate date payloads for check-in and check-out dates
      data = json.loads(self.default_payload)
        current_date = datetime.date.today()

        # Adjust the current_date if it's a Sunday (weekday == 6)
        if current_date.weekday() == 6:
            current_date = current_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)

        end_date = current_date + datetime.timedelta(days=30)

        checkin_dates = []
        checkout_dates = []

        # Generate check-in and check-out dates for the next 30 days
        while current_date <= end_date:
            if current_date.weekday() == 4:
                checkin_dates.append(current_date)

            if current_date.weekday() == 6:
                checkout_dates.append(current_date)

            current_date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)

        date_payloads = []

        # Generate payloads for each check-in and check-out pair
        for i in range(len(checkout_dates)):
            checkin_date = checkin_dates[i]
            checkout_date = checkout_dates[i]

            # Update the date in the payload data
            data['variables']['staysSearchRequest']['rawParams'][2]['filterValues'] = str(checkin_date)
            data['variables']['staysSearchRequest']['rawParams'][3]['filterValues'] = str(checkout_date)

            date_payload = json.dumps(data)
            date_payloads.append(date_payload)

        return date_payloads

def parse(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.text)

        info = data['data']['presentation']['explore']['sections']['sectionIndependentData']['staysSearch']['searchResults']

        for i in range(0, 17):
            date = strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
            id_value = info[i]['listing']['id']
            name = info[i]['listing']["name"]
            rating = info[i]['listing']["avgRatingLocalized"]
            PricePerNight = info[i]['pricingQuote']["structuredStayDisplayPrice"]['primaryLine']['accessibilityLabel'].replace("$", "").replace("total", "").strip()[:2]
            totalPrice_inDollars = info[i]['pricingQuote']["structuredStayDisplayPrice"]['secondaryLine']['price'].replace("$", "").replace("total", "").strip()
            
            # Extract check-in and check-out dates from the response data
            checkIn_date = data['data']['presentation']['explore']['sections']['sectionIndependentData']['staysSearch']['filters']['filterState'][4]['value']['dateValue']
            checkOut_date = data['data']['presentation']['explore']['sections']['sectionIndependentData']['staysSearch']['filters']['filterState'][5]['value']['dateValue']
            
            url = urljoin(self.rooms_url, id_value)

            yield {
                'date': date,
                'id': id_value,
                "title": name,
                "PricePerNight": PricePerNight,
                "totalPrice_inDollars": totalPrice_inDollars,
                "checkIn_date": checkIn_date,
                'checkOut_date': checkOut_date,
                "rating": rating,
                'url': url
            }
        #pagination
        url_path = data['data']['presentation']['explore']['sections']['sectionIndependentData']['staysSearch']

        # Retrieve the original payload from metadata
        x = response.meta.get('dpayload')

        for i in range(0, 13):
            payload_cursor = json.loads(x)
            page_cursor = url_path['paginationInfo']['pageCursors'][i]
            payload_cursor['variables']['staysSearchRequest']['cursor'] = page_cursor

            next_page_payload = json.dumps(payload_cursor)

            # Send a request for the next page
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=self.api_url,
                headers=self.headers,
                body=next_page_payload,
                method='POST',
                callback=self.parse,
                dont_filter=True
            )
```

The error occurs during the execution of this code, but it doesn't seem to prevent the spider from running and retrieving most of the data. However, I want to understand why this error is occurring and if it could potentially cause issues in the future. The error occured 56 times at first time, the number changes if I run it again.

Some additional context:

The code generates requests with different payloads for check-in and check-out dates.
The error appears in the parse method, specifically in the line where I'm trying to do pagination through payload sent as metdata. payload_cursor = json.loads(x)
Can someone explain why I'm getting this error and how it might affect my scraping process? Is there a way to handle it properly to ensure the reliability of my spider?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Haseeb Tahir\Desktop\workk\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 277, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
          ^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Haseeb Tahir\Desktop\workk\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 350, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Haseeb Tahir\Desktop\workk\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 350, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Haseeb Tahir\Desktop\workk\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 106, in process_sync
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\Haseeb Tahir\Desktop\workk\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 28, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if self._filter(r, spider))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Haseeb Tahir\Desktop\workk\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 106, in process_sync
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\Haseeb Tahir\Desktop\workk\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 352, in <genexpr>
    return (self._set_referer(r, response) for r in result or ())
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Haseeb Tahir\Desktop\workk\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 106, in process_sync
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\Haseeb Tahir\Desktop\workk\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 27, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if self._filter(r, spider))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Haseeb Tahir\Desktop\workk\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 106, in process_sync
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\Haseeb Tahir\Desktop\workk\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 31, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if self._filter(r, response, spider))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Haseeb Tahir\Desktop\workk\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 106, in process_sync
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\Haseeb Tahir\Desktop\workk\travelling\travelling\spiders\airbnb2.py", line 125, in parse
    payload_cursor = json.loads(x)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType
```

Comment: Because the value of `x` is `None`. Verify that you're setting it correctly.

Comment: Is the indentation in the post correct? You have `checkin_checkout` and `parse` nested inside `start_request`.

Comment: No It was a mistake in the post. I have corrected it.

Comment: post the full error message and traceback

Comment: i have the posted the error message. The error count was 45 this time

Comment: barmar answer is correct.  the value of x is None so calling json.load(None) causes an error.